# Tooltip problem when clicking on input in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently working on an HTML, CSS, PHP project. I want to display a tooltip to provide a small explanation to the user when the user clicks on an input field on a form. I want the tooltip to appear next to the input field but overlaying the form slightly but instead when it appears it wraps around the edge of the form instead of continuing. I have tried changing the z-index for the tooltip to 1 but it hasn't made any difference. The tooptip has been made with the use of HTML,CSS and JQuery. Below is the code that I have used to do this.

Below is the code for the form

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" style="margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;">
    <table class="formTable">
         <tr><td>
    <label for="txtUsername">Username: </label>
    </td>
    <td>
           <input class="forms" type="text" name="txtUsername" placeholder="Username" required autofocus />
           <span class="tooltip" style="z-index: 1;">Please enter your username</span>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>                    
            <td>
            <label for="txtPassword">Password: </label>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input class="forms" type="password" name="txtPassword" placeholder="Password" required /><br />
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">
                <div class="buttonGroup">
                <input class="button" type="submit" name="btnSubmit" text="Submit" /> <input class="button" type="reset" text="Reset" />        </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
       </form>
```

Below is CSS code for the form

```
form
{
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #95b0ff;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    z-index: 1;

}
```

Below is the CSS for the tooltip

```
.tooltip {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    background: #666;
    /*border: 1px solid #606060;*/
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: #ddd;
    -border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #111;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #999;
    z-index: 2;
 }
```

Below is the JQuery to show the tooltip

```
$(function() {
    $('.tooltip').hide();
    $('.tooltip').prev('input').focus(function(){
        $(this).next().fadeIn('slow');
    }).focusout(function(){
        $(this).next().fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @Rikudo Sennin this has sort of worked. The only problem I have now is that the tooltip doesn't appear next to the input field, instead it appears slightly underneath like in the image below

[image: Form showing tooltip not aligned with input]

Comment: maybe this will be of your interest? http://jsbin.com/pseudotooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position: relative` on the parent, and `position: absolute` on the tooltip.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/dbFZf/4/)**

Also, on an unrelated note, `for=` attribute for `<label>`s searches for `<input>`s with matching `id=`s not `name=`s.

Comment: Thanks this has sort of worked except the tooltip doesn't line up next to the input field instead it looks as if it has put it on a new line. How can I get it to line up i tried saying top: -20px but this didn't work. I have updated the question to show an image to explain what I mean. Thanks for your help

Comment: Actually `top: -someValuepx` should work. I'll update my example.

Comment: It didn't work because it would make it fixed to a position on the screen instead of being next to the clicked input field

Comment: @Boardy which is why I stated it should be used in conjunction with `position: relative` on its parent.

Comment: sennim I found out that instead of using top:-10px I should have used margin-top: -10px; Using this method works perfectly. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is what you're looking for :

```
.tooltip {
     position:absolute;
}
```